# Connecting an STM32 at Ethernet

Tags: stm32, ethernet

I am trying to connect the STM32F103 (blue pill) with the specific w5500 module via the SPI bus. The physical connection I made was

```
SCS  -> PIN14
SCLK -> PIN15
MISO -> PIN16
MOSI -> PIN17
```

Uploaded a [sample sketch](https://platformio.org/lib/show/261/Ethernet2) from Ethenet 2 library, but nothing works.
It seems like the processor or the module itself, keeps resetting.

I have connected successfully the Ethernet module previously on Arduino nano, with out any issues.

With the blue-pill, I cannot even find the device on the network while port scanning.

So two questions arise:

- Have I connected correctly the pins?
- Should I make any changes to the code to enable SPI at the bluepill, since it may serve two different SPI's?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "seems like the processor or the module itself, keeps resetting"? Even if you have nothing connected to the SPI pins or a malfunctioning slave device it should just cause your reads to fail. Do you get the same behavior when you completely disconnect the SPI pins?

Comment: I don't think your "Blue Pill" is even capable of connecting to a network. Is there supposed to be some WiFi chip? What exactly is the receiving end of this W5550 module?

Comment: From the script that you linked in your question, it indicates that: `A more advanced server that distributes any incoming messages to all connected clients but the client the message comes from. To use telnet to  your device's IP address and type.` However, I don't think this solution really applies to your configuration. You need to specify what your goals are here. I'm suspecting that you're trying to transmit your data _locally_ to your Blue Pill (via ethernet connection to SPI) but this script won't help you do that.

Comment: @KingDuken: The [W5500](https://www.wiznet.io/product-item/w5500/) is a complete SPI-to-Ethernet communications module.

Comment: Many STM32 have an integrated Ethernet MAC, and are powerful enough to run an IP stack. Therefore, the crutch which are W5500 (and similar modules that are mostly intended to be used with 8bit micros) are not necessary here. There are several STM32 eval boards available that feature an Ethernet connection.

Comment: @DaveTweed it is not. It is the complete SPI to TCP/IP solution :) /It of course includes the Ethernet*/

Comment: @KingDuken Actually it just connected to the network. Please check the solution offered.

Comment: @Erlkoenig I find no reason in spending a fortune for development boards, since i am a hobbyist. I actually found the issue by digging in the Ethernet2 library.

Comment: [22€](https://www.digikey.de/short/pfz4wv) is not a fortune.

Comment: @Erlkoenig It actually is, if you have already fried GPIO pins. I will keep that in mind though since i expected about double that price.

Comment: There may be cheaper ones. It was just the first that came to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided using SPI1 from the STM32 processor.

So, i mapped the physical connections as

```
SCS  -> PA4
SCLK -> PA5
MISO -> PA6
MOSI -> PA7
```

The trick was adding this line

```
 Ethernet.init(PA4);
```

before the method.

```
Ethernet.begin(mac)
```

By default, the pin used for Arduino is **PIN10**.

By using **Ethernet.init(PA4);** we override that pin, with **PIN14 (PA4)**,

suitable for STM32 and have a working solution.